# Moving tmux panes emulating i3 movement

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

In i3 an individual pane ([or window per i3 nomenclature](https://i3wm.org/docs/refcard.html)) is focused via `mod + j,k,l,;` and moved via `mod + Shift + j,k,l,;` where `mod` is some modifier key.

I have replicated the focus behaviour via binding `select-pane`, however cannot replicate the movement behaviour. `swap-pane` works in some circumstances, however for instance I would like applying `mod + (some down key)` where `B` is selected to apply

```
|-|-|
|A|B|
|-|-|

to

|---|
| A |
|---|
| B |
|---|
```

and similarly use 'smart' reordering logic for multiple panes.